# Is it possible to have quadratic time complexity without nested loops?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, complexity-theory

It was going so well. I thought I had my head around time complexity. I was having a play on codility and used the following algorithm to solve one of their problems. I am aware there are better solutions to this problem (permutation check) - but I simply don't understand how something without nested loops could have a time complexity of O(N^2). I was under the impression that the associative arrays in Javascript are like hashes and are very quick, and wouldn't be implemented as time-consuming loops.

Here is the example code

```
function solution(A) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js)
    var dict = {};

    for (var i=1; i<A.length+1; i++) {
        dict[i] = 1;
    }

    for (var j=0; j<A.length; j++) {
        delete dict[A[j]];
    }

    var keyslength = Object.keys(dict).length;
    return keyslength === 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

and here is the verdict

[image: result]

Comment: Have you tried recursion? :-) But indeed, in this case complexity should be linear to `A.length` and that tool seems buggy.

Comment: its codility,  a site which tests job applicants to see if they can code! They also have some interesting lessons - this one is a basic one from [lesson 2](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be a bug in their tool that you should report: this code has a complexity of `O(n)`.
Believe me I am someone on the Internet.

On my machine:

```
console.time(1000);
solution(new Array(1000));
console.timeEnd(1000);
//about 0.4ms

console.time(10000);
solution(new Array(10000));
console.timeEnd(10000);
// about 4ms
```

**Update**: To be pedantic *(sic)*, I still need a third data point to show it's linear

```
console.time(100000);
solution(new Array(100000));
console.timeEnd(100000);
// about 45ms, well let's say 40ms, that is not a proof anyway
```

Comment: To be pedantic, you'll still need a third data point to show it's linear

Comment: @Gareth: To be pedantic, you'll always find a polynomial of higher degree, regardless how many data points you have.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible to have quadratic time complexity without nested loops? Yes.  Consider this:

```
function getTheLengthOfAListSquared(list) {
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length * list.length; i++) { }
   return i;
}
```

As for that particular code sample, it does seem to be O(n) as @floribon says, given that Javascript object lookup should be constant time.

Remember that making an algorithm that takes an arbitrary function and determines whether that function will complete *at all* is provably impossible ([halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), let alone determining complexity. Writing a tool to statically determine the complexity of anything but the most simple programs would be extremely difficult and this tool's result demonstrates that.

Comment: Meh, it's proven that it's impossible to do for *every* arbitrary program. However, in reality it can be done for *most* programs, especially simple one like this (with its trivial input format).

Comment: Right, but it's still hard enough for this tool to fail at it.